# Apply BROWSABLE intent category to a broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I looked up the following intent filter for an activity in [commonsware samples](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Introspection/URLHandler/AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="www.this-so-does-not-exist.com"
        android:path="/something"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

However, the same intent filter doesn't work when applied to a broadcast receiver.

Could you point out whether it's possible to apply it to a broadcast receiver and if so where to look for a fix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the official documentation puts it:

> ...the Intent broadcast mechanism .. is completely separate from Intents that are used to start Activities with Context.startActivity(). There is no way for a BroadcastReceiver to see or capture Intents used with startActivity(); likewise, when you broadcast an Intent, you will never find or start an Activity. These two operations are semantically very different: starting an Activity with an Intent is a foreground operation that modifies what the user is currently interacting with; broadcasting an Intent is a background operation that the user is not normally aware of.

Source: [Android Developer Documentation, BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Hope that makes it clear.